# unresolved dependency for httpbuilder in groovy script

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

I am trying to automation using groovy script in soapui for that I want to use http-builder. I worte code like this

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder',modules='http-builder',version='0.5.2')
import statements
```

but when I run this it shows following exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.multipleCompilationErrorException:startup-failed Error Grabbing grape[unresolved dependency]javaRuntimeException
```

why I am getting this error. Is there any proxy problem?if yes where to add it?Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*SOAPUI* doesn't support *Grapes* as dependency management by default, so `@Grab` annotation doesn't work.

An alternative way to use `http-builder` is download all necessary libraries and place it on `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory, restart *SOAPUI* in order to load it. Then you can use it on *Groovy script* testStep adding the necessary imports and so on.

Hope this helps,

Comment: yeah I did that way finally. Thanks.

Comment: I surely do but I can't as I have less than 15 reputation:(